# How to see that someone made public channel private in Slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have no idea how to do it using EventsAPI from Slack.

So, our bot does this:

1. Creates public channel #test
2. Invites the bot to the channel using user token
3. From now on, we are using bot token to post messages on the channel

The problem happens when someone converts public channel to private. The ID of the channel changes and the bot gets error `channel_not_found`.

Do you have an idea how to track this change and update ID on our system automatically? Bot is still the member of the channel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way and it was also confirmed by Slack Help team.

Basically when channel is converted to private, you get these events:

1. `channel_deleted` with id of your public channel
2. `member_joined_channel` with id of new private channel and bot_id

When you get `member_joined_channel`, retrieve from Slack the name of new channel and if it matches your previous public channel then you know it is the same one but private now.

Slack does not allow to create channels with the same name so this is the indicator.

I just tested it with production app and it works! :)

Comment: This is a great answer. Please mark it as solution, so others can find it easier. ty

Comment: I'm not sure, but this is likely no longer true – Slack used to delete one channel and create another but it sounds like they support proper conversion now. https://api.slack.com/changelog/2018-09-more-reasons-to-be-a-conversations-api-convert#what

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is currently possible.

Naturally, you would expect a specific [Slack event](https://api.slack.com/events-api) for that case to fire, when a channel is converted, but there does not appear to be one. If you need this I would suggest to write a request they add an event for it.

One thing you can do is restricted who can create private channels in your Slack workplace to limit the risk of unintended use.

However, you can prevent this error from occurring by checking which public and private channels exist with [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list), and which channels you bot is a member with [`conversations.member`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members).